# how to avoid flask insert duplicate entries?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I want to update my database using the code snipped provided below:

```
@app.route('/update')
def update():
    os.system('python update.py')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

But when I use `gunicorn -w 4` to run the app and click the url `http://127.0.0.1:5000/update` once, it will run `python update.py` twice. The same content be insert into the database twice.I think it may be gunicorn's multiple processing cause the problem.

I also want to make the column unique,but it will not suit my need.

How can I solve the problem?
And could you tell me some good solutions to update database automatically every day.

Comment: What's writedatabase? Are you calling the same URL more than once? Is this your original indentation?

Comment: Should you really have an import statement in your loop, means youre importing writedatabase each time instead of just once? Shouldnt that be outside the loop? and then just use `h` within the loop.

Comment: for this you must have an unique column so that database will give duplication error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must only change state of a system, for example make any changes to a database, on `POST` requests. So:

```
@app.route('/update',  methods=['POST'])
def update():
    os.system('python update.py')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Otherwise you risk double run on multiple occasions, like browser preloading, browser restart, unclosing of browser tab and many others.

I'd also use `from . import update` instead of `os.system`.

Comment: Thanks!Your answer solved my problem!But I use this code to avoid it ,it didn't work when I click the /update post button twice. ```@app.route('/update', methods=['POST']) def update(): if 'updated' in session: return 'you have updated' session['updated']=True os.system('python update.py') return redirect(url_for('home'))```